# Swift - ADBannerView

Tags: swift, iad, ads, adbannerview

I tried to implement ADBannerView with the old way like Objective C but unsuccessfull. Everythings work but the advertisments didn't show up, it stays a blank field.

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
    banner.alpha = 1
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
    banner.alpha = 0
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Anyone who already tried iAd on Swift?

Comment: Hello, I am trying to use it, too. I've found the following: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/

Comment: add the delegate on top of your class by ", ADBannerViewDelegate" instead of the old way "<ADBannerViewDelegate>"

Comment: I would recommend you to use closures for your UIView animations: `UIView.animateWithDuration(1) { /* animations ... */ }`

Comment: Please verify your chosen answer as Mr. T's answer results in a duplicate ADBannerView

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've found a solution, how to implement it. (You can use inside each method "banner.alpha 1.0" or other things, too.)

```
//import ... your normal imports as UIKit etc.
import iAd

class YourClassViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

   @IBOutlet var adBannerView: ADBannerView //connect in IB connection inspector with your ADBannerView

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
      self.adBannerView.delegate = self
      self.adBannerView.hidden = true //hide until ad loaded
   }

   func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
      NSLog("bannerViewWillLoadAd")
   }

   func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
      NSLog("bannerViewDidLoadAd")
      self.adBannerView.hidden = false //now show banner as ad is loaded
   }

   func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
      NSLog("bannerViewDidLoadAd")

      //optional resume paused game code

   }

   func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
      NSLog("bannerViewActionShouldBegin")

      //optional pause game code

      return true
   }

   func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
      NSLog("bannerView")
   }

   //... your class implementation code

}
```

[See the following answer, on how to do it without IBBuilder!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771295/iad-in-xcode-6-with-swift/24788877#24788877)

Comment: I am not able to hide ad using this. 
self.adBannerView.hidden = true 

Any idea?

Comment: @RohitGoyal I've tested it another time and it still is working perfect for me with Xcode 6.0 (6A313). You could check if self.adBannerView != null and debug it. Without any code, we cannot help sorry.

Comment: Wouldn't this result into two `ADBannerView`s?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using iOS 7, extension methods and properties have been added to UIViewController to support handling of iAd:

See

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/index.html

To show an iAd you first need to add the iAd framework, go to the projects properties, general tab, add the iAd.framework in the Linked framework and libraries section.

In your view controller, import iAd to access the iAd extensions. And finally in viewDidLoad, set self.canDisplayBannerAds = true.

To remove ads, set canDisplayBannerAds to false

Note there is no need to create an AdBannerView in the story board or programmatically and there is no need for your view controller to implement the AdViewDelegate.

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //That's it
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mr. T answer contains a lot of useless code.

All you need is this part to show ads in your controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      canDisplayBannerAds = true
}
```

And when you don't need ads, you `canDisplayBannerAds = false`.

What it does — wrapping your controller into another controller with ad banner at the bottom. This feature is available since *iOS7*.

It's not possible to get delegate messages with it, so if you need it — you should replace it with `ADBannerView` instance variable.

Comment: No delegate methods? Well you can do it that way you suggest, but then you display an ad without finished loading - not that nice for the user. And if the user tap on the ad, you have to stop something in your app or game, thats possible with delegate methods only.

Comment: @Mr.T Without finished loading? What does it mean exactly?

Comment: @Mr.T Your downvoting shows that you don't understand what ```canDisplayBannerAds``` is.

Comment: Upvoted this one, since this should do the job. Adding another `ADBannerView` in the storyboard would result in two `ADBannerView`s, which Apple may reject since it violates its guidelines.

From what I understand from Apple's documentation, setting `canDisplayBannerAds` to `true` would already let the `UIViewController` handle showing/hiding of ads. I've only tried the one-line code, so, please tell me if what I assume is wrong.

Comment: @Christophr it's exactly as you wrote.