# iAd in xcode 6 with Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, iad, xcode6, adbannerview

I'm working to implement a banner ad in the scene, but it always reports "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=Oxdefe) and the program stops running.
I referenced [Mr. T's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695302/swift-adbannerview/24706196#24706196) in another question about iAd("Swift - ADBannerView") but still couldn't make it.

The code looks like this:

```
 import UIKit
 import SpriteKit
 import iAd
 class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var adBannerView: ADBannerView
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("view loaded")

    //iAd
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.adBannerView.delegate = self
    self.adBannerView.alpha = 0.0 
     if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
 //iAd
func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {


    println("sort of working1")

}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {


    self.adBannerView.alpha = 1.0 
    println("sort of working2")

}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {


    println("sort of working3")

}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {



    println("sort of working4")
    return true 
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {


}
}
```

And I created an ADBannerView in the Main.storyboard and linked it with the @IBOutlet adBannerView.

Anyone helps me figure out?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how I did it, possibly not all of it is necessary.

I did not use the banner in the Storyboard, so the IBOutlet is not necessary.

Also, if you manually create a banner, you do not need to set `self.canDisplayBannerAds`

This function (ported from ObjC) is how I display the ads.

```
func loadAds(){
  adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
  adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: adBannerView.center.x, y: view.bounds.size.height - adBannerView.frame.size.height / 2)
  adBannerView.delegate = self
  adBannerView.hidden = true
  view.addSubview(adBannerView)
}
```

This is called in `viewDidLoad`. Then, in the `didLoadAd` delegate method, I set `adBannerView.hidden = false` and in `didFailToReceiveAdWithError`, `adBannerView.hidden = true`

I think `hidden` is better than `alpha` in this situation, as it feels more natural. I believe (but am not sure) that when hidden, the view is not drawn at all by the GPU, while with an alpha of 0, it is still drawn, but made invisible (correct me if I am wrong).

This is my setup, and it worked for me, so hopefully it will work in your case too!

Comment: I tried to delete the line self.canDisplayBannerAds, and it worked!  for the hidden/alpha, I'm not sure which is better.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was trying to pause the game while I was interacting with the ad, which is indeed a must. I tried a lot of methods for hours but in vain. The best I could think of is simply put GameScene().paused = true in func bannerViewActionShouldBegin. But it never paused.

Comment: @Benzene That is why I did not use `canDisplayBannerAds`. It doesn't let you have this custom support

Comment: Yes I did delete that line, and that's why the ad could show up now. It didn't solve the pause problem. It's so frustrating.

Comment: There should be a way for you to pause the game when using that option but I contacted Apple tech support, no way to do it :|

Comment: I contacted them but still no response yet.    I'm trying your method now.  But it still won't pause at all. The scene is SKScene named GameScene, is it the right way to pause it with GameScene().paused = true ?  When I was debugging, all lines were executed but it simply won't pause.

Comment: No, it would be gameScene.paused = true. If you do GameScene().paused, you are creating an all-new scene. That is not what you want. Set the stored scene to be paused instead.

Comment: That makes sense! But if I use GameScene.paused = true, it reports error as "GameScene.Type does not have a member named'paused'" It's so wierd!

Comment: Do you have a property stored that is an instance of GameScene

Comment: You are right! Well...I put var gameScene = GameScene() in the GameScene class.When I put gameScene.paused = true, it reports " Use of unresolved identifier 'gameScene'".  Then I realized that I'd put it in the GameViewController and I did. No errors after that, but it still won't pause.

Comment: What is the line where you initialize the scene?

Comment: I simply put   init(size: CGSize){
        super.init(size: self.size) }   Does that matter?

Comment: No I mean where you set a variable equal to GameScene()

Comment: To not worry about the size, I deleted the init line in GameScene and the line to set it is  "let gameScene = GameScene() "  in the GameViewController class.

Comment: You need to store the scene as a property. Like, `class MyViewController{ var gameScene = GameScene() ...rest of class }`

Comment: Yes.  What I have is    class GameViewController{var gameScene = GameScene()  ....  } It seems the same to me.

Comment: Then, instead of when you say `let gameScene = GameScene()` take away the let

Comment: Yep.   I did changed that now. But it still doesn't pause, although no errors reported.  The code to pause it is `gameScene.paused = true` in  `func bannerViewActionShouldBegin`

Comment: Might be worth asking a second question for this part of your issue

Comment: I am getting ad loaded via delegates but ad is not displaying.

Comment: Your load function needs ()

Comment: @ericgu nice catch. Edit made.

Comment: You should also consider making hidden = false for new users

Comment: @ericgu You mean to put that line inside the load function? That wouldn't really make sense, because at that point, no ad is loaded.

Comment: @erdekhayser. Thanks for the prompt response. I mispoke as it was not clear what was going on. I think you may have to use super.addView(adBannerView) instead of self.addView(adBannerView)