# iAd Banner Implementation

Tags: xcode, swift, iad

I'm trying to implement **iAd** banner in my game programmed with **Swift**. So far I have had no success. **WWDC 2014** workshop videos only show implementation for objective-c.
Following the advice posted on other questions I have tried using this:

```
# import iAd

class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate  {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.adBannerView.delegate = self
    self.adBannerView.hidden = true
```

I have two compiler errors on `self.adBannerView.delegate = self` 
and on `self.adBannerView.hidden = true`

Both errors say:  `GameViewController does not have a member adBannerView.`

Comment: Here is an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771295/iad-in-xcode-6-with-swift/24788877#24788877

Comment: I still have the compilers errors, do you have any idea what could that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should unwrap optional to avoid error you mentioned in your post

```
self.adBannerView?.delegate = self
self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
```

P.S. found this example working https://github.com/ashishkakkad8/iAdBannerExample

[image: iOS simulator with example]

Comment: thank you, I definitely understood how to implement this thing thanks to your link.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared an instance variable named `adBannerView`.

If you've added the iAd BannerView in your storyboard, then create the instance variable and link it to the storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet var adBannerView: ADBannerView
```